# Next.js 13 App Directory Dynamic Routes do not work on prod build

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a backend where I enter some data and a Next.js Applicaton that will render the frontend with different components (images, videos, framer motion animations). I wanted to code a preview function that accepts a item id and renders the content for the item.

I call it with https://example.com/preview/1

The following code functions perfect in my development build. However when I publish my app to a static folder or to Vercel I end up with getting a 404 for the route. My folder structure is /app/preview/[id]

Code:

```
'use client';
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import { usePathname, useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation';

import { Container } from '../../../components/Container';
import ErrorBoundary from '../../../components/ErrorBoundary';
import { ApiUtils } from '../../../utils/api';

const apiUtils = new ApiUtils();
// Preview Page
export default async function Preview({ params }: { params: { id: number } }) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const mainContainerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const slug = params.id;            
  
  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const PREVIEW_API_URL = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PREVIEW_API_URL ?? '';
      const url = `${PREVIEW_API_URL}${slug ? `${slug}` : ''}`;

      const response = await fetch(url, { cache: 'no-store' });
      const result = await response.json();

      if (result === false) {
        // Handle error case
      } else {
          const data = result.data;  
          apiUtils.renderPreview(data);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle error case
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const rootInstance = apiUtils.initDOM(mainContainerRef.current!);
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <ErrorBoundary>
      <Container innerRef={mainContainerRef} id="mainContainer" />
    </ErrorBoundary>
  );
}
```

RenderPreview receives a JSX component and renders it to the rootInstance:

```
    renderPreview = (item: PlaylistItem) => {
        if (this.rootInstance !== null) {
            try {
                this.rootInstance.render(this.renderComponent(item));
            } catch (e) {
                console.log('Rendering failed.');
            }
        }
    }
```

If you need any other info please let me know. Thank you

I want it to be a client component and I want dynamic data, no prerendering etc. because it is a preview function. Basically everything is fine in development mode. I just cannot publish the app.

I read many articles and currently cannot figure out what causes the problem.

Comment: Did the vercel deployment build successfully?

Comment: have you solve the problem yet ? same issue here